# Unable to hit spring mvc controller through ajax call

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc, get-request

1.Below is my ajax call in index.jsp

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#buttonDemo1').click(function(){
                $.ajax({
                   method: "GET",
                   url: '${pageContext.request.contextPath}/ajax/demo1',
                   success: function(result){
                       $('#result1').html(result);
                   },
                           error: function(response){
                               console.log("error");
                           }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

2.Below is controller's code

```
  @Controller
  @RequestMapping("/ajax")
  public class AjaxController {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
   return "ajax/index";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/demo1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String demo1() {
      return "Demo 1";
     }
   }
```

3. Below is dispatcher's code

```
   <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
   <!-- was: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> -->
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="demo.controller" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>

<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />

<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
```

4. Below is web.xml

   ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
     <context-param>
   <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
   <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
   <listener>
   <listener-
   class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-
   class>
   </listener>
   <servlet>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <servlet-
   class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
   <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
   <servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
   <session-config>
   <session-timeout>
       30
   </session-timeout>
   </session-config>
   <welcome-file-list>
   <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
   </web-app>
   ```

I don't know what's wrong, whenever I'm hitting controller's path in ajax I get "GET http://localhost:8080/ajax/demo1 404 (Not Found)" error. Please help me out where I'm wrong. I've tried few solutions but they didn't resolve issue.

Comment: Do you see your controller instantiate in the log output?

Comment: @TheHeadRush yes I can see. Below are the logs:

Comment: Info:   Mapped "{[/ajax],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String demo.controller.AjaxController.index()
Info:   Mapped "{[/ajax/demo1],methods=[GET],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String demo.controller.AjaxController.demo1()
Info:   Mapped URL path [/ajax] onto handler 'ajaxController'
Info:   Mapped URL path [/ajax/*] onto handler 'ajaxController'

Comment: The Web.xml seems to map .htm extensions to spring

Comment: try `http://localhost:8080/ajax/demo1.htm`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the application name to the url,

http://localhost:8080/[AppName]/ajax/demo1

Comment: still same error.. "GET http://localhost:8080/DemoSpring/ajax/demo1 404 (Not Found)"